# Openpyxl is slow to load and save workbooks, how to improve speed?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

My goal is to copy a workbook, paste text in cells using a created list and save as a new workbook name.

Side note:

- the created list (impactVelocity11, PF35) has more than 1000 items in it.
- the workbook i'm trying to copy, size is 1961 KB, when code runs, new workbook size is around 2490 KB

Currently I am using Openpyxl, and my code works, but it is just ridicoulusly slow to load and save.

Partial code:

```
            wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('{0}\Template_VS.xlsx'.format(TemplateDirectory[-1]))
            sheets = wb.sheetnames
            print('Loaded workbook') ### Time is >1 min
            for s in sheets:
                if s == 'Info':
                    ws = wb[sheets[3]]
                    for i, value in enumerate(impactVelocity11, 2):
                        ws.cell(column=4, row=i + 1, value=value)
                    for i, value in enumerate(PF35, 2):
                        ws.cell(column=2, row=i + 1, value=value)
            print('Finished workbook') ### < 15 seconds
            wb.save('{0}\{1}.xlsx'.format(ValveSizingDirectory[-1],newcase))
            print('Saved workbook') ### > 1 min
```

I want to be able to do the same exact thing, but faster, is there any other work arounds, or are is it just this slow to load and save workbooks?

Comment: It's hard to beat MS Excel itself when it comes to file reading/writing speed. So consider using [`xlwings`](https://docs.xlwings.org): a package that enables python scripts to control and communicate with an active MS Excel application. What you could do is write a bit of xlwings python code that commands an Excel application to (1) load the Excel file, (2) write your data lists to cells and (3) save the Excel file.

Comment: Sort of depends on the file itself, especially if it has pivot tables or similar. I'd expect that kind of speed for a file of around 50 MB. Because XLSX files are zip archives, these **cannot** be edited in place so all the worksheets have to be loaded into memory and written back out.